# How to pass values from one activity to another for custom listview in xamarin.android and also saving application instance for listview

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin

am new in android development and am using xamarin.android. I am developing a application which contains two activities, Lets say A and B.
Activity A contains two edittext and a button, Activity B contains a custom listview. Now what i want to do is passing the values from both edittext in Activity A to the custom listview in Activity B.
I know how to create custom listview in the same Activity but dont know how to pass values to another Activity.
Also i need to save the application state, that is the list that is created stays there if the user clicks on back navigation key or even if user stops the application.

Comment: Did you try google it? You need to post what did you try so far or some researches... Check: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/

Comment: Please use the search - this is a commonly asked question

Comment: At least you have to try how to do. Then we can help you with your code.

Answer (score 1):

On Activity A:

```
// Open B Activity
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), B.class);
intent.putExtra("key1","value1");
intent.putExtra("key2","value2");
startActivity(intent);
```

On Activity B:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        String s1,s2;

        s1 = intent.getStringExtra("key1");
        s2 = intent.getStringExtra("key2");
}
```